# Issues with Discord bot's shop system: Second and third buttons not functioning properly

Tags: python, discord.py

Currently, I am developing a Discord bot with a shop system. I have created nine items divided into three buttons per page. However, only the first buttons on each page work correctly.

The second and third buttons do not generate any errors with the "print" functions I have used, but Discord returns "interaction failed". I feel like I have exhausted all available testing options and am going around in circles without a solution.

```
 @discord.ui.button(emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def on_buy_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        item_num = int(button.custom_id.split("_")[2]) % items_per_page - 1
        print(f"item_num: {item_num}")
        print(f"on_buy_button clicked for {button.custom_id}!")
        if item_num >= len(self.pages[self.current_page]):
            print("Invalid item number")
            return
        item = self.pages[self.current_page][item_num]
        print(f"item: {item}")
        
        article_id = item[0]
        article_name = item[1]
        article_price = item[3]

        if article_price > self.money_total:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have enough money to buy this item.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        conn = get_conn()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("UPDATE users SET money_spent = money_spent + %s WHERE user_id = %s", (article_price, self.ctx.author.id))
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()

        self.money_total -= article_price
        self.update_buttons()

        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You have purchased the item{article_name} for {article_price:.2f} :coin:", ephemeral=True)




    def make_embed(self):
        userAvatar = self.ctx.author.display_avatar
        embed = discord.Embed(title="╔.★. .═════════════╗\n     \n╚═════════════. .★.╝", color=0x1f5291)
        embed.add_field(name="", value="\u200b", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Wallet : `" + str(self.money_total) + "` :coin:", value="\u200b", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃▃", value="\u200b", inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=userAvatar) 

        # Add the list of articles of the current page
        for i, item in enumerate(self.pages[self.current_page]):
           
            embed.add_field(name=item[1], value=f"{item[2]}\n**Price:** `{item[3]:.2f}` :coin:", inline=True)
            article_id = item[0]  # Retrieve the item ID from the item list

            conn = get_conn()
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id = %s", (item[0],))
            article_info = c.fetchone() # Retrieve the article information from the database
            c.close()
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
                
            print(f"Index: {i}")
            print(f"Item: {item}")
            print(f"Article ID: {article_id}")

            if len(self.children) <= 3 + i or not isinstance(self.children[3+i], discord.ui.Button):
                # If the button does not exist yet, create it
                buy_button = discord.ui.Button(label=f"Buy the article {item[0]}", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, emoji="")
                buy_button.custom_id = f"buy_button_{item[0]}_{(self.current_page * items_per_page) + i}"
                print(f"Created button with custom_id: {buy_button.custom_id}")

                self.add_item(buy_button)
            else:
                # If the button already exists, reuse it
                buy_button = self.children[3 + i]
                buy_button.label = f"Buy the article {item[0]}"
                buy_button.custom_id = f"buy_button_{item[0]}_{(self.current_page * items_per_page) + i}"   
                print(f"Existing button reused: {buy_button.custom_id}")

            buy_button.disabled = item[3] > self.money_total

        self.children[len(self.pages[self.current_page]) + 3:] = []  # Remove excess buttons

        self.children[2].label = "Close"
        embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {self.current_page+1}/{len(self.pages)} | {self.ctx.author.name}#{self.ctx.author.discriminator} • {date}")

        return embed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Interaction failed" usually means that the `interaction` that Discord sent (when a user pressed the button) isn't being responded to - so Discord assumes something went wrong. It might be because your code is taking too long that it is timing out. If we [`defer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) at the start of your function - then we can take a little longer and then send the response using the [`followup`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook) property of `interaction`.

```py
@discord.ui.button(emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
async def on_buy_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)

    # the rest of your code here

    # replace interaction.response.send_message with interaction.followup.send
    await interaction.followup.send(
        content=f"You have purchased the item{article_name} for {article_price:.2f} :coin:",
        ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: First, thank you for your quick response. I tried to modify as in your answer, unfortunately the code remains as is. Buttons 2,3 / 5,6 / 8,9, still do not work.

Still this "failure of interaction" of Discord without error in the console.

But I had not thought that it could take too much time and prevent interaction.

Comment: Where are you defining the callback for these buttons? Are they all meant to be using the callback defined in the question?